# How to Get Values of an Object which is Inside other object

Tags: javascript, html

I am not from JavaScript background but have a small requirement where I am working with JavaScript.

I am trying to get the values inside an object which is enclosed in an other object, I have written the code but I am getting error. Below is my code, I am sure I have made mistake or may be the syntax is not right but could not able to resolve the issue.

This is the replica of the code with dummy values, can anyone please help me and address where I am doing wrong.

```js
            const nameList = [
                'XYZ',
                'ABC',
                'PQR'
            ];

            var person = {
                XYZ: {
                    name: 'XYZ',
                    age: 30
                },
                ABC: {
                    name: 'ABC',
                    age: 40
                },
                PQR: {
                    name: 'PQR',
                    age: 50
                }
            };

            var rowCount = 0;
            var releaseTableHTML = '';
            releaseTableHTML +='<table><thead>Just Testing</thead><tbody><tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr>';
            while (nameList.length > rowCount) {
                releaseTableHTML +='<tr><td>'+ person.nameList[rowCount].name+'</td><td>'+ 
                person.nameList[rowCount].age+'</td></tr>';
                rowCount++;        
            }
            releaseTableHTML +='</tbody></table>';
```

[image]

Comment: @Andy: `nameList` is an array...

Comment: You need to use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors#bracket_notation) around your dynamic property `person.[nameList[rowCount]].name`

Comment: try `person[nameList[rowCount]].age`

Comment: Yes, but when I try to get the value from namelist[rowCount] it is giving me ABC, PQR, XYZ as per rowCount value then it should become 'person.PQR.name' but it is not working

Comment: That is where the bracket notation comes in, allowing you to access the property through a variable

Comment: @Cerbrus I didn't say it wasn't an array. I just said it wasn't a property.

Comment: @Andy Cerbrus was indicating that your recommendation is trying to access `nameList` directly, not an element from `nameList`. Objects can't use arrays as property identifiers.

Comment: @Andy: You're saying an _array value_ is a valid variable to use in bracket notation. You're saying `person[['XYZ','ABC','PQR']]` is what the OP needs... You probably meant `person[nameList[someIndex]]`.

Comment: Thank you everyone ! Not only I achieved what I was looking for also I learnt something new today about Object, property, bracket notation in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

nothing hard, you arenot using the syntax to go data inside an object right you need to use this kind of thing:

```
const obj = {
  obj1: {
    a: 1
  }
};

console.log(obj["obj1"]?.a);
```

this is an exemple and this is how to do in your case at line 30

```
releaseTableHTML +='<tr><td>'+ person[nameList[rowCount]]?.name+'</td><td>'+
```

the thing is you can access attribut inside an object with [] and a string inside and here you string is the result of an array with this syntax arr[] so you want something like this -> obj[arr[]]

Answer (score 1):

There is no `nameList` property in `person`. Simply use `person[nameList[rowCount]].name` instead of `person.nameList[rowCount].name`.

Note that `nameList[rowCount]` gives you person's key and you can use it in `person` object.

```js
const nameList = [
  'XYZ',
  'ABC',
  'PQR'
];

var person = {
  XYZ: {
    name: 'XYZ',
    age: 30
  },
  ABC: {
    name: 'ABC',
    age: 40
  },
  PQR: {
    name: 'PQR',
    age: 50
  }
};

var rowCount = 0;
var releaseTableHTML = '';
releaseTableHTML += '<table><thead>Just Testing</thead><tbody><tr><th>Name</th><th> Age</th ></tr > ';
while (nameList.length > rowCount) {
  releaseTableHTML += '<tr><td>' + person[nameList[rowCount]]?.name + '</td><td>' +
    person[nameList[rowCount]]?.age + '</td></tr>';
  rowCount++;
}
releaseTableHTML += '</tbody></table>';


document.body.innerHTML += (releaseTableHTML);
```

Answer (score 1):

`nameList` isn't a property of `person` so you need to use the *value* of that array element as the property key so you can access the value.

I've adjusted your code a little to throw out the `rowCount` variable and just use a simple `for...loop`.

```js
const nameList=["XYZ","ABC","PQR"];
const person={XYZ:{name:"XYZ",age:30},ABC:{name:"ABC",age:40},PQR:{name:"PQR",age:50}};

let releaseTableHTML = '';

releaseTableHTML += '<table><thead>Just Testing</thead><tbody><tr><th>Name</th><th> Age </th></tr> ';

for (let i = 0; i < nameList.length; i++) {
  releaseTableHTML += `
    <tr>
      <td>${person[nameList[i]].name}</td>
      <td>${person[nameList[i]].age}</td>
    </tr>`;
}

releaseTableHTML += '</tbody></table>';

document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = releaseTableHTML;
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I just try to have less changes on your post. In this way you can show the columns.

```js
window.onload = function(){ 

const nameList = [
            'XYZ',
            'ABC',
            'PQR'
        ];

        var person = {
            XYZ: {
                name: 'XYZ',
                age: 30
            },
            ABC: {
                name: 'ABC',
                age: 40
            },
            PQR: {
                name: 'PQR',
                age: 50
            }
        };

        var rowCount = 0;
        var releaseTableHTML = '';
       releaseTableHTML +='<table><thead>Just Testing</thead><tbody><tr><th>Name</th><th>Age</th></tr>';
        while (nameList.length > rowCount) {
            releaseTableHTML +='<tr><td>'+ nameList[rowCount]+'</td><td>'+ 
            person[nameList[rowCount]]['age']+'</td></tr>';
            rowCount++;        
        }
        releaseTableHTML +='</tbody></table>';
        document.getElementById("test").innerHTML = releaseTableHTML;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"><div>
```